# pointer on method as an argument

Tags: c++, function-pointers

To avoid code duplication, I'm tring to pass pointers to functions as arguments of a static method.

I have a class (Geo) with only static methods. One of this methods (+++Geo::traceRay(+++)) should just display(Geo::display(+++)) few things, then return an int.

Another class (Las) needs to use the Geo::traceRay(+++) method, but should display(Las::display(+++)) someting else.
So I try to pass a pointer to function argument to the Geo::traceRay(+++, pointer to function) method. the pointed functon will the right "display()" method.

Up to now, passing the first pointer to display() is not an issue, but I can't find how to do it with the second one.

```
class Geo
{
public:
    static bool display(int pix);
    static int traceRay(int start, int end, bool (*func)(int) = &Geo::display); // no issue with this default parameter
};


class Las
{
public:
    bool display(int pix);
    void run();
};


int Geo::traceRay(int start, int end, bool (*func)(int))
{
    for (int i = start; i < end ; ++i )
    {
        if((*func)(i)) return i;
    }
    return end;
}

bool Geo::display(int pix)
{
    cout << pix*100 << endl;
    return false;
}


bool Las::display(int pix)
{
    cout << pix << endl;
    if (pix == 6) return true;
    return false;
}

void Las::run()
{
    bool (Las::*myPointerToFunc)(int) = &display;       // I can just use display as a non member class, but it should stay a member
    Geo::traceRay(0,10, myPointerToFunc);               // issue here!
}


int main()
{
    Geo::traceRay(0,10); // use the "normal display" = the default one// OK

    Las myLas;
    myLas.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a member function pointer as a function pointer. I presume making `Las::display` static is not an option. In that case, I would suggest taking a `std::function` and using `std::bind` to bind the current instance:

```
static int traceRay(int start, int end, std::function<bool(int)> func = &Geo::display);
...
Geo::traceRay(0,10, std::bind(&Las::display, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Also, in both cases, you can call `func` by:

```
func(i);
```

No need to dereference it first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I didn't know `std::function` and `std::bind`. I needed  [link](http://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/using-stdbind-for-fun-and-profit/)  to understand how it works, but now I have exactly what I wanted. Also, to call Geo::traceRay from the Las class, You have to use     `Geo::traceRay(0,10, std::bind(&Las::display, this, std::placeholders::_1));`

Answer (score 0):

What Chris suggests is great if that's as far as it goes.

Another approach to this, which would be beneficial if you have several shared functions like that, would be to use an interface (with a virtual method Display(+++)) with two implementations, put an instance of the implementation in question in each of Geo and Las (or Las could directly implement the interface).  Then traceRay takes a reference to the interface base class and calls the display method on it.